# Is there any way of having uncorruptable storage?

Tags: power-supply, storage

I'm looking for a way to have raspberry pi that I can just turn on and off without worrying about fs corruption (not out of laziness but because it is part of a machine that must behave that way) - knowing that the software writes to the disk every few seconds. The worst case scenario must be that some writes are lost if they occurred too early before a power loss, but that everything can boot back up again and keep on working.

- It could be hardware. I read somewhere that a USB stick inside an e-sata container could do this but I was unable to find any confirmation.
- It could be software if there s such a way. In particular some library that implements transaction-style writes where either everything is written or nothing is written (in case of power loss) at the end of a transaction.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. One way to do it is by setting up a [read-only filesystem](https://hallard.me/raspberry-pi-read-only/). When you want to write something, you switch over to read-write mode and once finished, back to read-only again.

The above link is one of many ways to do so, just to get you started. You can find many more examples by googling around.

Comment: But I'm guessing that the risk of corruption appears again when I switch to RW mode, and as I mentioned that's every few seconds... More than lower risk I'm looking for guarantees.

Comment: @schmop *that I can just turn on and off without worrying about fs corruption* is different from *before a power loss*. I guess you are not talking about the power going off deterministically (like you flipping a switch) because that's easy to handle, but random cut-offs instead. In that case, could you add a small UPS (large capacitor, battery etc.)? See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/safely-use-sd-cards-when-power-can-go-out-at-any-time and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8425/how-do-i-protect-sd-card-against-unexpected-power-failures